# Error when using single quotes in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, express, single-quotes

```
var comma = ","; 
var querys = "insert into movie values ("
           + "'" + movid + "'"
           +comma
           + "'" + name + "'"
           + comma
           + "'" + genere + "'"
           + comma
           + "'" + director + "'"
           + comma
           + "'" + description + "'"
           + ")";
```

I am having a problem with about code. I am building a website with express.js and mysql where the user can submit new movies to the site.

Most of the description submitted by users have a single in it (example: This movie wasn't shot in studio). Sentences like these gives an error.
I have tried using comma as variable and also "'" like this.

Any solution for this?
I can't make the users use \' because most of them don't know about it.

Comment: Surely there's a way to use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings like this?  This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Javascript String.Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function to replace all the ' characters with a \'
This way the users don't even have to think about it.